# how to use mbtiles file with arcgis api for android?

Tags: android, android-mapview, arcgis, mbtiles

I want to develop an `Android` app that needs to display maps but has to work offline all of the time with `arcgis API` for `Android`,and my data type is `.mbtiles` file.
How can I show `.mbtiles` file on `Mapview(ArcGIS Android SDK 10.2)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ARcGIS API for Android v 10.2 using which you can cache esri basemaps. Here is a link for the API help.

https://developers.arcgis.com/en/android/whats-new.html

if you still want to use .mbtiles then you have to integrate your local basemap tiles with elements of the ESRI SDK you will need to implement a custom AGSLocalTiledLayer class that points to an .mbtiles file (basically a SQLite database).